# strange C program fgets

Tags: c

I was going through an open source codebase and I see the following:-

```
char *buf;
char *line;
#define BUFSIZE 5000

buf = malloc(BUFSIZE)
line = buf;

while(fgets(line, (unsigned)(buf + BUFSIZE -line), in) != NULL) {
    // do stuff
    // ....
}
```

Why is the second argument to fgets given as `buf + BUFSIZE - line`?

Comment: is by any chance buf or line updated inside the loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That gives the number of characters from `line` to end of `buf`. Your `//do stuff` likely increments `line`

`buf + BUFSIZE` is a `char *` pointing to the first char *after* the memory allocated for `buf`

`buf + BUFSIZE - line` is an integral, the number of chars from `line` to `buf + BUFSIZE` - and therefore the number of characters you can safely write to `line` without overflowing `buf`

Answer (score 5):

`buf + BUFSIZE - line` gives the free space in the buffer.

This way `line` can be a scrolling pointer pointing to the first *free* byte, where the next read operation can put the data.

Answer (score 2):

Line will probably get incremented during the loop. Thus this expression shrinks the value of BUFSIZE by the size of text already read.

It's a guess, sicne you didn't post the loop.